# Update User's Email Directly in T-SQL?

Tags: 2007, email, user, update

We inherited a SP 2007 server.  We were told to use MembershipSeeder to manage users.  One of the users has misspelled email address.  MembershipSeeder does not have option to update email address.  We deleted and re-created the user with correct email address using MembershipSeeder but the misspelled address is still shown.

Is it supported if I updated the SQL table directly to correct email address for the affected user?

Comment: Let me see if I understand, You have a site with fba, right?
Your users are stored into a database, right?

If I get it (just if I get it), you can perform any actions in DML SQL, so yes you can create a query to perform an update of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the user [using PowerShell](http://www.codeovereasy.com/2012/08/change-users-display-name-in-sharepoint-2007-using-powershell/) without having to hit the database. You can also use some [server side C# code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2de6e79-2cbf-44b2-ad89-bfb22b99a7dd/change-users-email-address-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious). Personally, I prefer to use PowerShell because it's relatively quick and painless.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$site = Get-SPSite http://example.com
$web = $site.RootWeb
$user = $web.SiteUsers.GetByEmail("usr@example.com")
$user.Email = "user@example.com"
$user.Update()
```

As a general rule of thumb, changes to SharePoint should be done though the API's and not at a direct database level. In this case, a change to the UserInfo table would probably be safe, but I would still advise against it as an error could lock people out of the site collections.

Quick aside: When you deleted the user, you didn't actually remove the user from SharePoint. There is still a record in the UserInfo table that contains the misspelled address that is associated with the file (hence the wrong email displayed). The new user account that you created is different than that user with the incorrect email address.